# Getting NullPointerException from my Service class (Spring MVC + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm practicing with some Spring MVC + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate app, I use Tomcat as server and MySQL as database. So I've met problem, I continue getting NullPointerException on userServiceImpl class. Also, if I remove empty constructor from controller, I'll keep getting error like about bean creating, even though I haven't created it in previous projects and everything worked fine. How to fix these ones?

**Absence of empty controller constructor error:**

```
\`Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file \[E:\\github\\task2.2.3\\task223\\target\\task223\\WEB-INF\\classes\\web\\controller\\UserController.class\]:...


Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file \[E:\\github\\task2.2.3\\task223\\target\\task223\\WEB-INF\\classes\\web\\controller\\UserController.class\]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate \[web.controller.UserController\]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:...

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate \[web.controller.UserController\]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: web.controller.UserController.\<init\>()
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
...
```

**NPE UserService error:**

```
\`HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "web.service.UserService.save(web.model.User)" because "this.userService" is null

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "web.service.UserService.save(web.model.User)" because "this.userService" is null

Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "web.service.UserService.save(web.model.User)" because "this.userService" is null
web.controller.UserController.allUsers(UserController.java:26)
```

**Configurations:**

AppInit

```
package web.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;


public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

WebConfig

```
package web.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("web")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("web.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext appContext, Environment environment) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(appContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emFactory.setPackagesToScan("web");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return emFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package web.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import web.model.User;
import web.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public UserController() {   // remove to get error
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String allUsers(Model model) {

        userService.save(new User("one", "ones1", 2000));
        userService.save(new User("twe", "ones2", 201));
        userService.save(new User("tree", "ones3", 2200));
        userService.save(new User("for", "ones4", 20320));
        userService.save(new User("o", "ones5", 20002));


        model.addAttribute("allUsers", userService.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String user(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(id));
        return "user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return "add";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(id));
        return "edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute User user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        userService.update(id, user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        userService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
package web.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "birthYear")
    private int birthYear;

    public User(String name, String surname, int birthYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", birthYear=" + birthYear +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
package web.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import web.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**UserService interface:**

```
package web.service;

import web.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {
    List<User> findAll();
    User findById(Long id);
    void save(User user);
    void update(Long id, User user);
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

**UserService implementation:**

```
package web.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import web.model.User;
import web.repository.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        Optional<User> foundUser = userRepository.findById(id);

        return foundUser.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Long id, User updatedUser) {
        updatedUser.setId(id);
        userRepository.save(updatedUser);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**POM dependencies:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>task223</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>task223 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

<!--    Test-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!--    Servlet-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


<!--    Template engine-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    Spring-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--    Hibernate-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--    DB driver-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.25</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>task223</finalName>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>8</source>
                  <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've tried to recreate database, change Long to int in User model and corresponding methods, cleared target folder.

Comment: I am unsure, but I believe auto-wiring UserServiceImpl instead of UserService could work.

Comment: Tried changing UserService to UserServiceImpl -> Same story, same null. :(

Comment: Link to github with this project:

https://github.com/avevivi/task2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

The MAIN problem was wrong folder structure.
Also maybe: Spring and Spring Data JPA versions incompatibility.

Comment: This should be commented

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
```

To the properties of the `pom.xml`.

Comment: java: error: invalid flag: -maven.compiler.parameters

can't run, get this error

Comment: @savemysoul Add the xml to the properties of the pom.

Comment: I have to make this app without xml, java code only, so I can't use xml :(

Comment: You tell me you have absolutly no `pom.xml`? So your POM dependencies are not real? So your github-link to https://github.com/avevivi/task2.2.3/blob/master/pom.xml does not exists?

Comment: I was sleepy, didn't see that was about pom, not xml configuration.
Anyway, before previous comment I've tried to put "<maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>" in pom, so it caused invalid flag error.

But I really appreciate any help, thanks very much!

Comment: I said to the properties of the pom. You need a node properties.